# ORA-00904: "FOODSUPPLY"."FOODSUPPLYID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Faced ORA-00904 Error when performing INNER JOIN. What is the cause and how to solve it?

```
Error : PL/SQL: ORA-00904: 
"FOODSUPPLY"."FOODSUPPLYID": invalid
     identifier
```

There are multiple (F1)Chicken and I want only the DISTINCT value

Eg: (F1) can only appear once in (S001), but can still appear in (S002)

```
SELECT s.shelterID,'('|| fs.foodSupplyID ||') '||fs.foodSupplyName AS foodSupplyDesc
FROM FoodSupply FS,Victim V,Shelter s,Shelter_allocation sa
INNER JOIN Request R ON Request.foodsupplyID = FoodSupply.foodSupplyID
WHERE   r.victimID = v.victimID
    AND fs.foodsupplyID = r.foodSupplyID
    AND r.victimID=sa.victimID
    AND SA.shelterID=s.shelterID
ORDER BY s.shelterID,requestDate;
```

Current Output:

```
shelterID | foodDesc    
S001      | (F1)Chicken  
S001      | (F3)Beef     
S001      | (F1)Chicken  
S002      | (F1)Chicken  
S002      | (F5)Meat    
S002      | (F1)Chicken
```

Desired Output:

```
shelterID | foodDesc       
S001      | (F1)Chicken    
          | (F3)Beef       
S002      | (F1)Chicken  
          | (F5)Meat
```

Comment: Don't mix the ANSI 92 syntax of explicit `inner join` with the older syntax of implicit joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - you missed the alias name

However, it's better to use explicit join

```
 SELECT distinct s.shelterID,'('|| fs.foodSupplyID ||') '||fs.foodSupplyName AS foodSupplyDesc
    FROM FoodSupply FS INNER JOIN Request R ON R.foodsupplyID = FS.foodSupplyID
    Inner join Victim V on R.victimID = V.victimID
    Inner join Shelter_allocation sa on R.victimID=sa.victimID
    inner join Shelter s on sa.shelterID=s.shelterID
    ORDER BY s.shelterID,requestDate
```

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't mix `,` and `JOIN` in a single query.  Copy this answer's pattern. Using `, ` to join tables is never a good idea.